# How can I use Zfill or Format while writing to a file in hex?

Tags: python, format

I was wondering how I can pad a number with zeroes while still writing to a file as hex. The only way I know of to write a file in hex in Python is by using chr().

```
paddednumbers = int(1)
with open('pads', 'w+') as source_file:
    with open('pads', 'wb') as dest_file:
        dest_file.write(chr(paddednumbers))
```

This writes it without the padding since I obviously didn't supply it, this is when my problem comes in.

Since chr() wants me to supply something in int() form, and zfill likes using anything but int() form, I'm in a bad situation.

This is how I set up zfill:

```
paddednumbers = hex(int(1))[2:].zfill(8)
```

If we convert this back to int() so I can try to write this to my file in chr(), of course I still get the number 1 as used in the code.

What's a solution to this? Is there another module/function I can use or am I missing something?

Comment: `chr` doesn't return hex, it returns an ASCII character

Comment: What format is your file in?  There are many file formats that look like hex characters when viewed in a text editor (utf16, etc.)

Comment: I'm not trying to encode text with UTF-16, UTF-8, etc. It seems chr() will write to a file as hex. What I'm trying to do is make the hex padded so it can be like an "unsigned int 32" in C++.

Comment: All files are written as binary data.  When you see "hex" in a file, that's just one of the ways to display binary data, which usually hasn't been properly decoded.

Comment: @Larsenv: Do you mean hex, as in ASCII text using the set of hexadecimal characters 0-9, and either a-f or A-F, or do you mean "I want to write raw bytes, binary data, to the file"?

Comment: Also, why is `pads` being opened twice, both as source and dest? That seems fishy.

Comment: I meant write a file in binary form. Like if I took a "FF" byte, I want to write that byte and not in its text form.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem probably lies in a better understanding of unicode and character encodings.

[This article is a must read](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for any programmer attempting to understand unicode and encodings -- **written by one of the founders of StackOverflow, Joel Spolsky, no less.**

All files are written in binary at the lowest level.  When you say you want to write "hex" to a file, I'm guessing you mean you want to encode your ASCII strings in some format that looks like hex when you print it out as a byte string.

```
>>> s = '1'.zfill(4)
>>> s
'0001'
>>> s.encode('utf_16')
'\xff\xfe0\x000\x000\x001\x00'
```

You could write the encoded data to a file.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(s.encode('utf_16'))
```

And then read it back in:

```
>>> with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
...    encoded_string = f.read()
...
>>> encoded_string
'\xff\xfe0\x000\x000\x001\x00'
>>> encoded_string.decode('utf_16')
'0001'
```